# What happens when using MySQL Insert Delayed inside a transaction?

Tags: mysql, insert, transactions, commit

Does the inserts are finished with the transaction commit? Or they can be finished later?

Comment: I don't understand why one would want to use a delayed insert inside a transaction... Can you elaborate your use case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-delayed.html):

> INSERT DELAYED works only with MyISAM, MEMORY, ARCHIVE, and (as of MySQL 5.1.19) BLACKHOLE tables. For engines that do not support DELAYED, an error occurs.

None of these engines support transactions, so there's no conflict in functionality here.

I would imagine that you will find that support of delayed inserts and transactions will be mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

Insert delayed don't work with engines that support transactions