# Error: 1031 SQLSTATE: HY000 (ER_ILLEGAL_HA) - Meaning?

Tags: mysql

What does this error mean?

**`MYSQL - Error: 1031 SQLSTATE: HY000 (ER_ILLEGAL_HA)`**

I can find a million references on the MySQL site to this error - but can not find the definition for it.

- Anyone know the definition? Meaning?
- Or a good place to reference these errors?

I have been exporting a database from a production area - and importing to a development testing area, for over a year now. And have used the same selections on export/import every time. Today, it reports this error on a **INSERT DELAYED INTO** command during import.

I have selected a transaction with, **Add DROP TABLE, Add IF NOT EXISTS, Add AUTO_INCREMENT value, Complete inserts, Extended inserts, Use delayed inserts** on my my exports. Because I want to ensure the copy I place in the development database, is overwritten and that creates an exact copy of the development database.

I would love to know why after a year it now reports this error - and a good place to look the meaning of these errors up.

Thank you.

Regards.

Comment: As per the question/answer I refer to: `Insert delayed don't work with engines that support transactions`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no Table Engines that support both Transactions and InsertDelayed. Attempting to use both will cause ER_ILLEGAL_HA error.

**What ER_ILLEGAL_HA Means**

Basically this error appears whenever you try to use a feature that is not supported by your table SQL engine.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_illegal_ha

Has someone modified your database and assigned a different storage engine to a table?

**INSERT DELAYED and Transactions causing ER_ILLEGAL_HA**

In Addition have a look at the following very interesting question:

- [What happens when using MySQL Insert Delayed inside a transaction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403530/what-happens-when-using-mysql-insert-delayed-inside-a-transaction) and Especially this answer:
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2403591/1688441

Quoting from that answer:

> **"INSERT DELAYED works only with MyISAM, MEMORY, ARCHIVE, and (as of
>   MySQL 5.1.19) BLACKHOLE tables. For engines that do not support
>   DELAYED, an error occurs."**
>
> None of these tables support transactions, so there's no conflict in
>   functionality here.
>
> I would imagine that you will find that support of delayed inserts and
>   transactions will be mutually exclusive.

Comment: This link >>> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_illegal_ha Is the same I found - says nothing about the actual error and its meaning. It only provides the same error message the MySQL has already given me. "Message: Table storage engine for '%s' doesn't have this option" 

What is the point of providing an error reference manual where they only reiterate what the MYSQL engine just spit back at you?!?! For debugging - a possible cause or definition of the meaning of the error - would be a lot more helpful - then just reiterating the same error message.

Comment: I wonder if - the database size has increased to a point where it actually used the 'Delayed' feature and this threw the error?

Answer (score 0):

From the mysql [*Server Error Codes and Messages* documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/error-messages-server.html):

> Error: 1031 SQLSTATE: HY000 (ER_ILLEGAL_HA)
>   Message: Table storage engine for '%s' doesn't have this option

Comment: This is simply reiterating the same error message the MYSQL sent me - it is the point of this post, that there is no definition of the actual error message. I am looking for a definition of the error message - not the error message repeated somewhere else with little to no meaning. What option?

Comment: I agree with KDawg, it does seem to be the case.